# Pass Multi Value to Project Parameter SSIS

Tags: parameters, ssis, project

Can anyone please help me with this. 
I want to send Multiple value as a project parameter to SSIS package that has been deployed. 
I have created environment for the configuration.

Is there anyway where I can provide more than 1 value to the Project Parameter.

Example. I run a package with @ProjectPara_DistrictID  = 1 .
Suppose I want to run the same with values 1,2,4,5,6,7,8

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

use for loop container and use that variable inside the container

You can specify the value and the increment value for that variable as normal as in C language

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter is an `Int` datatype (and I would assume it is), and you can't change that datatype because it is shared by other packages, then you cannot pass multiple values to it.

However, if you can change the datatype to a string, then you can pass a comma-delimited string, and handle the multiple values in the package code.